# Cassandra integration with hadoop for read performance

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I am using Apache Cassandra for storing around 100 million records. There is one single node with the following specifications-

```
RAM-32GB, HDD-2TB, Intel quad core processor.
```

With cassandra there is a read performance problem. For some queries it takes around 40mins for giving the output. After searching for how to improve the read performance i came to know about the following factors-

```
Compaction strategy,compression techniques, key cache, increase the heap space, turning off the swap space for cassandra.
```

After doing these optimizations, the performance remains the same. After seraching, I came around for integrating Hadoop with cassandra.Is it the correct way to do the queries in cassandra or any other factors I am missing here??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you data model could be improved. 40 minutes is something impossible. I download all data from 6 million records (around 10gb) within few minutes. And  think it because I convert data in the process of download and store them. Trivial selects must take milliseconds.

Did you build it [on the base of queries that you must do](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/) ?

Comment: The data model is quite simple. Because of the huge amount of data we had shifted from MySQL to Cassandra. The data model is built on the basis of the queries. If I give a query where the number of records is less, the output is very fast whereas this is not the same with queries including huge records. So i think I am missing some factors. Can you just help me for improving the read performance in cassandra???

Comment: Well, your question is very wide. You  write that you did all the thing that is possible for the optimization, so I suppose you have some "side" problems - did you check performance of your OS ? maybe some problems with HD ? Did you check your queries carefully ? maybe you use "ALLOW FILTER " or so.  I think, you need to put more information in to the question.

Comment: The HDD which I am using is 2TB. OS is Fedora 20. After getting so much time delay in one node, I have created a cluster of two nodes, so that whatever queries i pass, it will be distributed. with this the time delay was decreased to 30mins. I have used secondary indexes for some columns so that filtering can be possible.  The heap space i have allocated is 50% of the RAM. The CPU processing speed fluctuates within a range of 50-200%. I have read in some posts of stackoverflow to turn off the swap space for cassandra. I tried it but it didnt worked for my scenario.